# ActionBarSherlock set horizontal progressbar max value programmatically

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

I'm using ACB in my application and I have a little issue with setting max value of horizontal progress's max value.As I can understand (and found / read over internet) there is a way to set the horizontal progressBar using xml in it's own style like

```
<item name="android:max">value</item>
```

But in my application I am downloading data and depending on some values the user can download different kind of packets / information and I need to set progressBar's max value programmatically. And that max value will be changing on every packet depending on it's size.

Any ideas how can I increase max value everytime and calcutate the progressbar's current value depending on that?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I can see there is no way to update horizontal progress bar's max value at runtime, except setting it in xml styles.

If anybody else found a solution for this please answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
ProgressBar pg = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext());
pg.setMax(100);
```

For sherlock `progressbar` you can use this sample code: in this code set the value of `mProgress`  to set the max value of `progressbar`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;

public class Progress extends SherlockActivity  {
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mProgressRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mProgress += 2;

            //Normalize our progress along the progress bar's scale
            int progress = (Window.PROGRESS_END - Window.PROGRESS_START) / 100 * mProgress;
            setSupportProgress(progress);

            if (mProgress < 100) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mProgressRunner, 50);
            }
        }
    };

    private int mProgress = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //This has to be called before setContentView and you must use the
        //class in com.actionbarsherlock.view and NOT android.view
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.progress);

        findViewById(R.id.go).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mProgress == 100) {
                    mProgress = 0;
                    mProgressRunner.run();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: with this code you are creating a new ProgressBar, but I need to get the progressBar which is added by using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);` and update it's max value.